# Working with actions in cordova local notifications

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I've installed cordova local notifications plugin for local notifications in my app. However I'm unable to get notification actions work in my code.

Here's my code.

```
scheduleTime: String = '08:15';  //default

scheduleAlarm(){

    this.date = this.datePipe.transform(this.date,"yyyy-MM-dd");
    var reminder_date = new Date(this.date+" "+this.scheduleTime);
    var hours = reminder_date.getHours();
    var minutes = reminder_date.getMinutes();

    if(reminder_date){

        cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
         id: 1,
         text: 'My first notification',
         trigger: {at: reminder_date},
         actions:[{id: 'yes', title: 'Yes'},{id:'no',title:'No'}]
        })

        this.showAlert('Reminder is set successfully');
    }

 cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("yes",function(notification){
    alert(notification.id);
 });
}
```

After clicking on yes nothing is happening, just that the notification is dismissing. Am I handling it correctly? Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it in onDeviceReady().

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('Running cordova-' + cordova.platformId + '@' + cordova.version);
    document.getElementById('deviceready').classList.add('ready');

    // Add this code here
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("yes",function(notification){
        alert(notification.id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the launch property to your actions array and set the bool to true.

```
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
     id: 1,
     text: 'My first notification',
     trigger: {at: reminder_date},
     actions:[{id: 'yes', title: 'Yes', launch: true},{id:'no',title:'No'}]
    })
```

So when you click on yes, it will launch the application.